# JDialog and its owner

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to use a few JDialogs inside my form JPanel to notify the user of incorrect data and form submission.

I'm just a bit confused with the JDialog constructor. I'd want to link the dialog to the panel (only because that's where it's created), but obviously the only owner parameters that are allowed are  top level Frames (which I don't think I can access from the JPanel), or a Dialog (which I can't see helping me).

I could pass a reference for the Frame down to the JPanel, but isn't that a bit strange design wise? Or am I misunderstanding the class, or just more generally where the JDialog should be instantiated?

Hope I've made myself clear, I can make a sscce if it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the only owner parameters that are allowed are top level Frames (which I don't think I can access from the JPanel

You can access the parent frame of the panel by using:

```
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( yourPanelHere );
```

Then just use the window as the owner of the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

[JComponent.getTopLevelAncestor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getTopLevelAncestor--) gives you the owner of the JPanel:

> Returns the top-level ancestor of this component (either the
>   containing Window or Applet), or null if this component has not been
>   added to any container.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DialogTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                DialogFrame frame = new DialogFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}

/**
  * Frame contains menu. When we choose menu "File-> About" JDialog will be shown
 */
class DialogFrame extends JFrame {

    public DialogFrame() {
        setTitle("DialogTest");
        setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);

        // Menu
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        // Add About & Exit.
        // Choose About - > About
        JMenuItem aboutItem = new JMenuItem("About");
        aboutItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if (dialog == null) //if not
                {
                    dialog = new AboutDialog(DialogFrame.this);
                }
                dialog.setVisible(true); // to show dialog
            }
        });
        fileMenu.add(aboutItem);

        // When Exit 
        JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        exitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        fileMenu.add(exitItem);
    }

    public static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 300;
    public static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 200;

    private AboutDialog dialog;
}

/*
 * Modal dialog waits on click
 */
class AboutDialog extends JDialog {

    public AboutDialog(JFrame owner) {
        super(owner, "About DialogTest", true);

        // Mark with HTML centration
        add(new JLabel(
                "<html><h1><i>Все о Java</i></h1><hr>"
                + "Something about java and JDialog</html>"),
                BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // When push "ok" dialog window will be closed
        JButton ok = new JButton("ok");
        ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        // Button ОК down of panel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(ok);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(260, 160);
    }
}
```